# Shell script in Mac Automator won't work with folders

Tags: bash, mac, shell, script, automator

I am creating a service in Mac Automator which is basically a bash script to change some dcm files with dcmodify. Whenever I run it on a single file it works flawlessly, but when I try to run it over an entire folder it will print **an error**:

```
E: unable to load file [...]: No such file or directory
```

Here is the script, I really have no clue about what I could be missing:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    Accession="$(/usr/bin/basename "$(/usr/bin/dirname "$f")")"
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.7/bin/dcmodify -m "(0008,0050)=$Accession" "$f" -nb
    Patient="$(/usr/bin/basename "$(/usr/bin/dirname "$(/usr/bin/dirname "$f")")")"
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.7/bin/dcmodify -m "(0010,0010)=$Patient" "$f" -nb
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.7/bin/dcmodify -m "(0010,0020)=$Patient" "$f" -nb
done
```

PS: I'd like to clarify that when the error comes up it is referred to the folder I want to run.

E.g. if I try to run it on Desktop/asd **the error message** will be:

```
E: unable to load file /User/Desktop/asd: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Tip: While debugging a script, consider putting `set -evx` at the top of the script so you can see exactly what's being executed before and after parameter expansion (variable substitution) has happened. You can use `set +evx` to undo it later. Of those three shell options, `-x` is the most important here.

Comment: Added it above the code but the error message doesn't add much more. Thanks for the tip anyway, didn't know about it!

Comment: Have you tried running your shell script directly in the shell (via  a terminal emulator like Terminal.app or iTerm) instead of in Automator? It would be nice to be able to eliminate some kind of Automator integration issue as a contributing factor.

Comment: I just did it and I got the exact same error

Answer (score 2):

## Your first problem is the variable assignment in the loop.

Let's say I have files. I made it with `touch file\ with\ space{001..010}.txt` and `touch file{001..010}.txt`

```
file with space001.txt
file with space002.txt
file with space003.txt
file with space004.txt
file with space005.txt
file with space006.txt
file with space007.txt
file with space008.txt
file with space009.txt
file with space010.txt
file001.txt
file002.txt
file003.txt
file004.txt
file005.txt
file006.txt
file007.txt
file008.txt
file009.txt
file010.txt
```

let's debug you script.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    DIRNAME="$(/usr/bin/dirname "$f")"
    BASENAME_DIRNAME="$(/usr/bin/basename "$(/usr/bin/dirname "$f")")"
    echo "$f"
    echo $DIRNAME
    echo $BASENAME_DIRNAME
done
```

the result is :

```
file with space001.txt
.
.
file with space002.txt
.
.
file with space003.txt
.
.
file with space004.txt
.
.
file with space005.txt

<ellipsis>
```

And this is the way the script run.

```
+ for f in '"$@"'
/usr/bin/dirname "$f"
++ /usr/bin/dirname 'file with space001.txt'
+ DIRNAME=.
/usr/bin/basename "$(/usr/bin/dirname "$f")"
/usr/bin/dirname "$f"
+++ /usr/bin/dirname 'file with space001.txt'
++ /usr/bin/basename .
+ BASENAME_DIRNAME=.
+ echo 'file with space001.txt'
file with space001.txt
+ echo .
.
+ echo .
.
<ellipsis>
```

The debug shows `$f` don't have an absolute path.
I believe that is not what you want as `Accession` variable.

To get an absolute path, use `realpath` command.
To use `realpath`, you need to install coreutils via `brew install coreutils`

I suggest add this command in the loop.

## This fixes the first problem.

my `realpath`'s path is `/usr/local/bin/realpath`. yours may have different path. To find the path of the `realpath`, `which realpath`

`f=$(/usr/local/bin/realpath "$f")`

```
for f in "$@"
do
    f=$(/usr/local/bin/realpath "$f")
    DIRNAME="$(/usr/bin/dirname "$f")"
    BASENAME_DIRNAME="$(/usr/bin/basename "$(/usr/bin/dirname "$f")")"
    echo "$f"
    echo $DIRNAME
    echo $BASENAME_DIRNAME
done
```

## The second problem is that Zsh in the Automator does not work as Zsh in a terminal.

This is because they have different `setopt` settings. The detailed zsh option explanation is [zsh options](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html).

I can write a more concise and intuitive script, but the difference in `setopt` can cause an error.

**So you should write a shell script differently.**
The difference can be fixed, but now it's too time-consuming for the script.

## The suggestion for your code.

```
#If you choose a directory.
if [[ -d $@ ]]
then
    # if you select a directory which contains files.
    for f in $@/*
    do
        f=$(/bin/realpath $f)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.7/bin/dcmodify -m "(0008,0050)=$Accession" "$f" -nb
        Patient="$(/usr/bin/basename "$(/usr/bin/dirname "$(/usr/bin/dirname "$f")")")"
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.7/bin/dcmodify -m "(0010,0010)=$Patient" "$f" -nb
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.7/bin/dcmodify -m "(0010,0020)=$Patient" "$f" -nb
    done
#If you don't choose directory.
else
    # if you select files.
    for f in $@
    do
        f=$(/bin/realpath $f)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.7/bin/dcmodify -m "(0008,0050)=$Accession" "$f" -nb
        Patient="$(/usr/bin/basename "$(/usr/bin/dirname "$(/usr/bin/dirname "$f")")")"
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.7/bin/dcmodify -m "(0010,0010)=$Patient" "$f" -nb
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dcmtk/3.6.7/bin/dcmodify -m "(0010,0020)=$Patient" "$f" -nb
    done
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply! Sadly, I have not enough experience to understand all of it. The script uses dcmodify command for DICOM Toolkit to change some values in DICOM files. What I need is to change 1 of these values using the name of folder containing the file and 2 values with the name of the parent directory. I've put the code together browsing on the web.

I just want to point out that the script works when action is called on one or more files directly but fails when applied to a whole folder containing files.

Comment: Anyway, I have installed coreutils with homebrew and added f=$(/bin/realpath "$f") in my script right after "do" (using the path I got using "which" in Terminal), but it still won't work

Comment: What was the error message? Also can you add `echo $Accession` after the assignment to check your assignment works.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you said works?

Comment: I added the solution and an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

By longstanding Unix convention, all options (i.e. command-modifiers that begin with a hyphen or two, like `-v` or `--verbose`) are expected to go before all positional arguments (like the list of filenames you want the command to act on).

So you probably need to rewrite this:

```
dcmodify -m "(0008,0050)=$Accession" "$f" -nb
```

…to this:

```
dcmodify -m "(0008,0050)=$Accession" -nb "$f"
```

As you have it now, `dcmodify` is finding a filename and assuming the rest of the command line will be filenames, but it's not finding a file named `-nb`, so it's reporting an error.

(You'll occasionally find tools that don't follow this convention, but it's usually a sign that they were poorly ported from MS-DOS by a DOS-minded person who was not savvy to venerable Unix traditions.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know that and when reading documentation I often find myself where to place modifiers. Sadly, the error persists. I suspect it could be something not strictly related to the code but some global setting, though I have no idea what could be